# Consuming a .net web service with java not showing expected results

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf

I'm having problems to consume a .NET Web Service from a simple Java Application. I'm only testing right now if the web service client fetches the expected data, and apparently it doesn't. I created a Web Service Client in Eclipse using the wsdl location and it went right. Also, I've tested the methods in the .NET side and they are working alright. So the problem must be something I'm missing when using the methods generated by the Web Service Client. I'll show the code which is almost ridiculy simple:

```
package com.consumeserviciodirectorio;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;
import org.tempuri.*;
import org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.DAL_DirectorioCide_Modelo.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {

IDirectorioCIDEProxy d = new IDirectorioCIDEProxy();
String resp = d.jerry("ya");
System.out.println(resp);
ModeloEmpleadoParaDirectorio[] lista = d.consulta("Paterno=|osorio|");
System.out.println(lista.length);
for(ModeloEmpleadoParaDirectorio res:lista){
System.out.println("Nombre: "+res.getNombres()+" Apellidos: "+res.getPaterno()+" "+res.getMaterno());
System.out.println("Area: "+res.getAreaDescripcion()+" Email: "+res.getEmailCia());
}
}
catch (AxisFault e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()+ " "+e.getFaultReason());
}
catch (RemoteException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
    }

}
```

Also, the code in the .NET end is like so (it's tested and it works with the parameter as I'm passing it above):

```
public List<Modelo.ModeloEmpleadoParaDirectorio> Consulta(string Consulta)
        {
            List<Modelo.ModeloEmpleadoParaDirectorio> _result = new List<Modelo.ModeloEmpleadoParaDirectorio>();
            try
            {
                using (EvolutionCatalogosEntities modelo = new EvolutionCatalogosEntities())
                {
                    Consulta = Consulta.Replace("|", "\"");
                    _result = (from U in modelo.Empleado
                               join C in modelo.CatAreas on U.ActInstId equals C.IdCatArea
                               select new Modelo.ModeloEmpleadoParaDirectorio
                               {
                                   Id = U.Id,
                                   Nombres = U.Nombres,
                                   Paterno = U.Paterno,
                                   Materno = U.Materno,
                                   AreaDescripcion = C.AreaDescripcion,
                                   EmailCia = U.EmailCia
                               }).AsQueryable().Where(Consulta).ToList();
                }
                return _result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return _result;
            }
        }
```

However the variable called `lista` is an empty array no matter what I do, meaning that it's length is 0. There must be something I'm missing but I've used the same method to call the web service before and it worked. Can someone point out what's the problem with that code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer debugging the service on the .NET end. The problem was there was a missing connection string of the model in the web.config of the svc. I knew the code wasn't a problem, on any of the points connecting. Sorry for posting a question that was probably not related to the actual problem.